# Workaround needed for SASS/Compass compile error when creating custom Ext-JS 4 themes

Tags: extjs, sass

I am using Compass 0.11.5 with SASS 3.1.15 to create a custom theme in Ext-Js 4. Everytime I try to compile, I get the same error:

error my-ext.theme.scss (Line 115: Functions may only be defined at the root of a
document)

The hang-up seems to be on the @import statement with 'ext4/default/all'. Like others I have tried for days to find a solution for this and could only come up with using an older version of SASS (3.1.11) but I can't find that anywhere online.

Is there another workaround or can someone please show me where to get the 3.1.11 version of SASS?

Go easy on me as I am a Graphic Designer not a Programmer :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- getting sass 3.1.11: gem install sass -v 3.1.11
- removing sass 3.1.15: gem uninstall sass -v 3.1.15

You'll still likely run into additional problems, referenced here, with solutions: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?158358-4.0.7-Syntax-errors-when-compiling-SASS-themes

Upgrading to Ext JS 4.1 RC 2 might also be a viable option for you

Answer (score 0):

The combination that worked for me to build ExtJS 4.1.1 css is:

- Ruby 1.9.3p547
- Sass 3.2.5 (Media Mark)
- Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam)